# what is window size?

Tags: filters

i am working on simulation of an article "A Real-time ECG Data Compression Algorithm for a Digital Holter System". This algorithm has five steps "Difference=> ECG Signal=>Classification=> DCT=> Window Filter => Huffman" . it described window filter as "In order to implement a high compression ratio, the DCT window size, which is chosen to be proportional to the DCT result, is adjusted from 15% to 100%.". i do not understand this step and how can i do it? how can i change window size? 
please help me
thanx

Answer (score 1):

[That paper is very poorly written.](https://www2.lirmm.fr/lirmm/interne/BIBLI/CDROM/ROB/2008/EMBC_2008/PDFs/Papers/11980335.pdf) It's no wonder you have a hard time understanding it; I certainly did!

What I think is happening is that several of the DCT coefficients are being thrown out (windowed). So if the window is 100%, then all the DCT coefficients are kept; if the window is 30% then 70% of the coefficients are thrown out (zeroed).

See Figure 11 of that paper:

[image]

The left hand signal are the DCT coefficients. The right-hand graph is the applied window. The two are multiplied together.

Comment: Peter - thanks, must be something on my end.

Comment: @Mohammad Make sure you're using the HTTP_S_ link. HTTP doesn't work.